# Magento 1.7 redirecting URLs when URL rewrite table empty and non in htaccess?

Tags: magento-1.7, .htaccess, 301-redirect, redirect-url

Im just cleaning up my site and sorting out all the 404s in webmaster tools. To fix the 404s I was just putting in a manual 301 in the htaccess file like this.

```
Redirect 301 /football-rebounders/spot-rebounder/kickster-spot-7-x-7-rebounder.html http://www.quickplaysport.com/football-rebounders/spot/spot-rebounder-7x7.html
```

This was working fine until I tried to add the line above and I noticed it didnt redirect correctly. I thought it was something Id entered wrongly but couldnt find any problems with it so in trying to diagnose the problem I completely wiped my URL_rewrite table and deleted all the 301s in htaccess but the site kept redirecting even without anything in either of these, so my question is what is making my site redirect now if not the htaccess file or the URL rewrites in the table? I have tried refreshing the cache

The page I have trouble with is this one:

http://www.quickplaysport.com/football-rebounders/spot-rebounder/kickster-spot-7-x-7-rebounder.html

if you click the link, you will see the URL gets forwarded to this:

http://www.quickplaysport.com/football-rebounders/spot//kickster-spot-7-x-7-rebounder.html

so it is seems to be forwarding part of the URL and then appending the rest onto the end of that.

this has really confused me as it had been working fine for the other 50 or so redirects Id added.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do you think there is an extension causes the issue ? Try disabling them one by one in etc/modules

Comment: 301 redirects can be cached *browser-side* so you may just be seeing that. Try a different browser or different computer.

Comment: Thanks, thats it, it was being cached in the browser. After I tried on a clean browser I was able to diagnose that I had my 301s in the wrong order and part of  the URL was being rewritten by a line higher up and so the URL didnt match by the time it got to the correct 301